# row and column specifications in xtable output

Tags: tables, r, sweave, knitr, xtable

Using `xtable` I am trying to format a table

```
x<- 1:5
y<- 11:15
mytable <- table(x,y)
print(xtable(mytable))
```

Which gives:

[image]

I want to add `x` and `y` tags also at the top of the rows and sides like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have a package called [**printr**](https://github.com/yihui/printr), which has not been published to CRAN but might be useful to you. See [its vignette](http://yihui.name/printr) for more information. Note you need to install the development versions of [**knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) and **printr** from Github.

Here is a preview of results from R Markdown, and it should not make a difference if you use it .Rnw documents. The positions of x and y may not be what you want, though.

[image: print tables with printr]